# Роль Femtolisp в Julia

Tags: lisp, julia

Обнаружила у интерпретатора *Julia* ключ *--lisp*, при указании которого первый вместо привычного приглашения выводит:

```
;  _
; |_ _ _ |_ _ |  . _ _
; | (-||||_(_)|__|_)|_)
;-------------------|----------------------------------------------------------
```

Насколько мне известно *Femtolisp* - это один из побочных проектов Джеффа Безансона, одного из разработчиков *Julia*. Может мой вопрос покажется довольно наивным, но какой смысл было встраивать один интерпретатор в другой? Или все же, как можно только догадываться, он играет некую сакральную роль в *Julia*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле Femtolisp не такой уж и побочный проект, так как в устройстве Julia занимает центральное место: он отвечает за синтаксический анализ текта программы перед его отправкой далее компилятору LLVM для генерации машинного кода. Со стороны это может показаться несколько надуманным, однако в виду незначительного потребления памяти и хорошем быстродействии в купе с гибкостью, Femtolisp, как проект предшествующий Julia, в качестве парсера - вполне логичный выбор. Да и что дурного в том, что наряду с интерпретатором Julia получаем один из диалектов Lisp?!

```
> (define (fac n) (if (<= n 0) 1 (* n (fac (- n 1)))))
#fn("8000r1e0|`32640a;|e1|ax31T2;" [<= fac] fac)

> (fac 10)
3628800
```

Оценить быстродействие Femtolisp предлагаю самостоятельно.

Comment: Не, я в Lisp не разбираюсь. Спасибо за разъяснения!